# Copying value from one input field to another input field

Tags: javascript, html

I need a javascript function for copying the value of one input field to another input field based on checkbox selection. However i did some javascript code on click,

```
<script>    
function copyTextValue() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
    document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
    document.getElementById("Name3").value=text1;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="copyTextValue();"/>
```

Now i need to delete the copied values in those two boxes on uncheck. I stuck up with this. Any help?

Comment: That function should work, please show us the html for those three inputs. I guess you're confusing `name` and `id`. Also, you might want to make the `check1`box a `type="button"`

Comment: It is working fine. But it should delete the values when i uncheck the checkbox, this is not working, Here is the html,

<input type="text" id="Name1" />
<input type="text" id="Name2" />
<input type="text" id="Name3" />

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="copyTextValue();"/>

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NTFAP/

Answer (score 13):

```js
function copyTextValue(bf) {
  var text1 = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("Name1").value : '';
  document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
  document.getElementById("Name3").value = text1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);" />
<input id="Name1"><input id="Name2"><input id="Name3">
```

Comment: Could you please make an update to the answer if you were to use a multi-select input and copy those items over to another textbox?

Comment: @Harold_Finch I will recommend to ask a new question instead and ping me if no one replies

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do for unchecking:

```
    document.getElementById("Name2").value ="";
    document.getElementById("Name3").value="";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyTextValue() {

    if(document.getElementById('check1').checked){
        let text1 = document.getElementById('Name1').value;        
        document.getElementById('Name2').value = text1;
        document.getElementById('Name3').value = text1;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('Name2').value = "";
        document.getElementById('Name3').value = "";
    }    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="Name1" name="Name1">
  <input type="text" id="Name2" name="Name2">
  <input type="text" id="Name3" name="Name3">  
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" onclick="copyTextValue();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using upper ans I copied Billing address into shipping address in woocommerce

```
 function copyTextValue(bf) {
        var billing_first_name = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value : '';
        var billing_last_name = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_last_name").value : '';
        var billing_address_1 = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_address_1").value : '';
        var billing_address_2 = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_address_2").value : '';
        var billing_city = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_city").value : '';
        var billing_state = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_state").value : '';
        var billing_postcode = bf.checked ? document.getElementById("billing_postcode").value : '';
        document.getElementById("shipping_first_name").value = billing_first_name;
        document.getElementById("shipping_last_name").value = billing_last_name;
        document.getElementById("shipping_address_1").value = billing_address_1;
        document.getElementById("shipping_address_2").value = billing_address_2;
        document.getElementById("shipping_city").value = billing_city;
        document.getElementById("shipping_state").value = billing_state;
        document.getElementById("shipping_postcode").value = billing_postcode;
        
      }
```