# Auto complete form field from previously entered value on the same form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am building quite a long form that has multiple form fields and check boxes.
In order to make it as usable as possible from the client perspective I would like to auto populate certain values as the client fills out the form.

This form contains different sections as the client goes through the form. 
So if he has entered his First Name, Last Name and ID Number in the first section he would be prompted to do so again in a later section( this is due to legal obligations). I would like to auto populate these fields from the clients first entries as to make the process a little easier and more user friendly.

What would be the best way to go about this?

If I am correct in saying that I cannot have two of the same values in a form when it is submitted to the database. It makes more sense to have one value but auto populated from the first.

Hope this makes sense.

```
<h3>Section 1</h4>
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="text" name="client_first_name" id="client_first_name">         
    <label for="client_first_name">Client First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_last_name" id="client_last_name">           
    <label for="client_last_name">Client Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_id" id="client_id">
    <label for="client_id">Client ID Number:</label>    
<li>
    <label for="advisor_name">Advisor:</label>
    <select type="text" name="advisor_name" id="advisor_name">
        <option>Please Select Advisor</option>
        <option value="andrew">Andrew</option>
        <option value="jamie">Jamie</option>
    </select>

    <label for="advisor_id">Advisor ID Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="advisor_id" id="advisor_id">
</li>
</ul>

Later in document......

 <h3>Section 7</h4>
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="text" name="client_first_name" id="client_first_name">         
    <label for="client_first_name">Client First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_last_name" id="client_last_name">           
    <label for="client_last_name">Client Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_id" id="client_id">
    <label for="client_id">Client ID Number:</label>    
<li>
    <label for="advisor_name">Advisor:</label>
    <select type="text" name="advisor_name" id="advisor_name">
        <option>Please Select Advisor</option>
        <option value="andrew">Andrew</option>
        <option value="jamie">Jamie</option>
    </select>

    <label for="advisor_id">Advisor ID Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="advisor_id" id="advisor_id">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this will give you the answer that you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662715/copying-value-from-one-input-field-to-another-input-field

Comment: and you need to remember that you can only use an ID once on a page, the ID always needs to be unique, even if you are using it to collect the same data.

Comment: If in the same page you need different IDs.

Comment: The JSFiddle you gave uses a checkbox to assist in the auto pupulate. Don't want a check box to auto populate the other fields. Suppose I could use a "next" button to do the same thing?

Comment: why don't you just copy values that are going to repeat. e.g. Current Address, Permanent address

Answer (score 0):

If in the same page you need different IDs.

You can do this

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ae8dL5t2/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var names=["client_first_name","client_last_name","advisor_name"],fields={};
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
    var fieldSet = document.getElementsByName(names[i]);
    if (fieldSet.length==2) {  
      fields[names[i]]=fieldSet[1];
      if (fieldSet[0].type.indexOf("select")!=-1) {
        fieldSet[0].onchange=function() {
          fields[this.name].selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex;
        }
      }
      else fieldSet[0].onkeyup=function() {
        fields[this.name].value=this.value;
      }
    }  
  }
}
```